# Docker without docker dekstop. How to run Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I want to run docker container on windows without docker desktop.

I dont know how it could work.

I installed Ubuntu on Windows (from Microsoft Store).

In Windows cmd i can write 'wsl' and then it brings me to Ubuntu cmd. In Ubuntu i installed Docker and its working.

Now I have project on Windows with Dockerfile. How can i run it ?
Because i have two systems Windows with my project and Linux with docker. What i have to do now to makes it works ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your WSL navigate to your Dockerfile location. `/mnt/c` is the windows C: drive location inside the WSL. Build your Dockerfile with [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/). Run it with [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/). If the docker commands complain about the docker daemon not being reachable you need to start it with `sudo service docker start`.